# Setting up Cassandra Liquibase

Tags: java, jdbc, cassandra, classpath, liquibase

I'm trying to set up cassandra liquibase.
https://github.com/liquibase/liquibase-cassandra

**Executed code from terminal:**

```
java -jar  ~/.m2/repository/org/liquibase/liquibase-core/3.4.1/liquibase-core-3.4.1.jar  \
  --driver=org.apache.cassandra.cql.jdbc.CassandraDriver  \
  --classpath="/.../liquibase-cassandra/target/liquibase-cassandra-1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar:/.../liquibase-cassandra/target/cassandra-jdbc-1.2.5.jar"  \
  --changeLogFile=/.../conf/liquibase.xml  \
  --url=jdbc:cassandra://host1--host2--host3:9160/keyspace1 \
  --username=cassandra \
  --password=cassandra \
  update
```

> **Error:** Unexpected error running Liquibase: Could not initialize class org.apache.cassandra.cql.jdbc.CassandraDriver

I'm not sure what is the right syntax to use liquibase cassandra extension. I cloned liquibase-cassandra project, created a jar with mvn and assumed that `org.apache.cassandra.cql.jdbc.CassandraDriver` mentioned in `liquibase.ext.cassandra.database.CassandraDatabase` class is the jdbc driver I need. 
I don't have any experience with liquibase, I'm still in college and my knowledge is still quite vague in some areas.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As error suggests, I had problem with jdbc driver. I couldn't connect to Cassandra database using SQLWorkbenchJ and that driver either. I'm not sure if the problem was with my url syntax.

I tried using different jdbc driver.  `com.github.cassandra.jdbc.CassandraDriver`. Jar: `cassandra-jdbc-driver-0.6.4-shaded.jar` and url for jar: https://github.com/zhicwu/cassandra-jdbc-driver/releases.

Url syntax for this specific driver: `url=jdbc:c*://ipaddress:port`.

```
java -jar  /.../.m2/repository/org/liquibase/liquibase-core/3.4.1/liquibase-core-3.4.1.jar \
  --driver=com.github.cassandra.jdbc.CassandraDriver \      
  --classpath="/.../cassandra-jdbc-driver-0.6.4-shaded.jar:/.../liquibase-cassandra/target/liquibase-cassandra-1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar:/.../log4j-1.2.17.jar" \     
  --changeLogFile=/.../conf/liquibase.xml \       
  --url=jdbc:c*://127.0.0.1:9042 \      
  --username=cassandra \      
  --password=cassandra \   
update
```

This worked. :)

Comment: Can you please tell us which version of cassandra you used ?